# Living Weapon and Hammer of Nazahn

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Hammer of Nazahn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433292) out (which allows me to attach any equipment to a creature as it enters the battlefield), will it work with a living weapon such as [Batterskull](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233055)? Would Batterskull's "living weapon" ability force it to equip to a Germ creature or could I still use Hammer of Nazahn's ability to attach it to any creature I wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both abilities trigger at the same time, so you can place them on the stack in the order of your choice. If you place [Hammer of Nazahn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHammer%20of%20Nazahn%5d)'s ability on the stack first, then it will resolve last. This means you will first attach the equipment to the Germ creature when the triggered ability from Living Weapon resolves, then you may attach it to a different creature when [Hammer of Nazahn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHammer%20of%20Nazahn%5d)'s ability resolves.